# Flutter: mainAxisAlignment and crossAxisAlignment properties is not working in child Row

Tags: flutter

I can't use mainAxisAlignment in child Row
I have added my code syntax below please help me with this

**My output**

[image]

**Desired output**

[image]

```
 Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: <Widget>[
        Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, // here mainAxisAlignment not working
            children: <Widget>[
                new Container(...),
                new Container(...),
        ],),
        Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,// here mainAxisAlignment not working
            children: <Widget>[
                new Container(...),
                new Container(...),
        ],),
],),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happening because child Row Widgets don't have any size. You can wrap your Row with Expanded widget and use flex property to give size to each row.

Following code will help you more.

```
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 7,
        child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment
                .spaceEvenly, // here mainAxisAlignment not working
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(),
              new Container(),
            ]),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 3,
        child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment
                .spaceEvenly, // here mainAxisAlignment not working
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(),
              new Container(),
            ]),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Second Solution:

You can add SizedBox with specific width in between Containers to add space.

Comment: This will overflow in some cases. I do not recommend.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must decide constant spacing and dynamic spacing.

The circular avatar and icons must have constant spacing, so you can add `padding` parameter to first `Container`.

Once you done it, put `Spacer()` between name `Column` and first `Icon`. It will fill the spacing between name and icons.

If you share your code more detailed I can help better.